# Symfony, where to put custom methods on entities?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony and I'm trying to figure out where to put custom actions over an Entity...

For example, if I have an entity `Order`, where to put `$order->complete()`? Or `$order->sendToProduction()`, `$order->queueForDelivery()`?

Those are just examples, I have complex entities and I must perform on them many actions.

In the Controller?

- No, because the same action may be called from different controllers

In the Entity?

- That would be the more appropriate way in a MVC model, but here I can't find an easy way to perform custom mysql query (doctrine/em is not available) from inside the Entity class, which I find strange since db operations should be perfomed at the Entity level, I believe...

In the EntityController?

- It doesn't seem appropriate, and it's not easy to call repository methods from a listener, for example, and call them directly on the object...

What else? Do I have to create services? Utility classes?

Comment: "That would be the more appropriate way in a MVC model, but here I can't find an easy way to perform custom mysql query (doctrine/em is not available) from inside the Entity class, which I find strange since db operations should be perfomed at the Entity level, I believe" No, entities (or models) should be totally decoupled from your storage engine. Actually, they should be decoupled from anything else and should be able to live alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the work can be done inside a signle entity (and it's relations of course) then it should be placed there. I mean, if the operation is about changing entity's **internal** state.

Otherwise, if this job need to use other parts of application like database, or is performed on multiple not related entites, then I would suggest using [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

That's what where are for. Service is basically a class that can do anything. Using Service container, you can pass any dependencies to it so it's very flexible and easy to use.

For example `$order->queueForDelivery()`. That may mean a few different things:

- changing internal state like change `status` to `queued_for_delivery` - then it should be in `Order` entity class
- `$order` should be put in the `Queue` that is other entity class, then it should be in `Queue` class like `$queue->addOrder($order)`
- this queue is an external service like RabbitMQ or anything else. Then you should use a service class.